# vector parametrization

Tags: calculus, limits

The Bernoulli spiral is parametrized by $r(t) = \langle e^t \cos(4t),e^t \sin(4t) \rangle$

A bug crawls along the spiral, according to the parametrization $r(t)$, starting at the beginning of time, $t=-\infty$. What is the bug's starting position at the beginning of time?

Not sure how to take the limit of this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Michael and welcome to the site.  Some good-to-know things is that it is encouraged to typeset your questions. It will make more people want to read and maybe answer. If my edit comes into effect you can click "edit" to see how to write math to become typeset. Other than that it is encouraged to show any effort you have done in trying to solve the problem and where you get stuck.

Comment: This bug is clearly very old. But what happens if you put neg infinity for t into your parametric equation? When you raise the e-power to neg infinity, you pretty much get the answer.

Comment: when you raise e to neg infinity you get 0*cos(-infinity). Can you just say cos will be between -1 and 1 and the limit will be 0?

Comment: Yep since you know a bound on one of the functions and the other goes to 0 you can do that.